# Ubuntu installation on a hybrid HD with little SSD space

Tags: system-installation, ssd, hybrid

I've just bought my ultrabook Lenovo Flex 14 8GbSSD 500HDD. I want Ubuntu 14.04 as the main OS running on SSD. I used and installed ubuntu 12.04, 13.04 and now 14.04 on my old notebook, but I don't know how to do the installation properly now on this hybrid.

I simply don't know what to do and how to do it:

1) what should I put on SSD and what should I put on HDD? E.g. should I put \Home on SSD or on HDD?

2) how to do this? I can make ubuntu run on my pendrive but don't know how to do the  installation properly. I've tried to do a simple installation, erasing W8 but it didn't work.

I only saw tutorials about double boot, but I will run windows on VirtualBox, so the problem is how to install ubuntu properly on SSD.

I've tried to install Ubuntu erasing Win8.1, but it was taking much time, then I aborted it. Now when I choose “something else” in installation it shows:

```
/dev/sda
free space      size: 1Mb  
/dev/sda1 efi       size:536Mb      used:33Mb
/dev/sda2 ext4      size:495367Mb   used:11152Mb    system:Ubuntu 14.04 Lts
/dev/sda3 swap  size:4201Mb used:0Mb
free space      size: 1Mb;
```

Device for boot loader installation:

```
/dev/sda ATA ST500LM000-1ej6 (500.1Gb); 
/dev/sda1;
/dev/sda2 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (14.04);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to keep your existing drive as well as the SSD, which is what I now have, I'd install to everything to the SSD except /home and swap. During installation, ensure you give the correct locations (eg /dev/sda5) and tell the installer NOT to format the partitions. After installation, edit your /etc/fstab file to put /var/log and /tmp on the HDD. There's plenty of help on this forum for this - it looks worse than it really is!

I was in a similar situation with my Lenovo G510 and a hybrid disk drive which has 8GB SSD. It's a Seagate ST1000LM014-SSHD and as such the SSD part works as cache only. It needs no drivers and linux cannot even see it as a separate drive. See [here.](http://www.seagate.com/files/www-content/product-content/momentus-fam/momentus-xt/laptop-sshd/en-gb/docs/sshd-0107-1-1302-%20po-gb.pdf) As your machine running a Seagate ST500LM000 it has the same technology as mine where they have their own internal implementation of caching. Apart from updating firmware, there is nothing else to worry about with them. Your drive details are [here.](http://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/docs/pdf/datasheet/disc/laptop-sshd-kit-ds-1784-4-1401us.pdf)